# How to change propagation from rprivate to rshared?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/opt/docker-substantiator/app",
    "Destination": "/app",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
```

This is how the inspection of my .mount currently appears. My application needs to access and to change a file in one of the subdirs of /app. So I am trying to change from rprivate to rshared. I added bind-propagation: rshared to the docker-compose but that doesn't seem to work. I restarted the container but the inspect still shows rprivate.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same issue, did you find any solution for that?

Comment: I did not. In my case, that was not the issue. It was an issue of the owner of the file in the container was not the same owner as on the host. It was eventually fixed by using chown.